# How to know if there is some code before a comment in java using kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, text-parsing

I'm interested in writing some code to detect a special case in java code where we have code with some comments on the same line.

`int i = 10 //here is the comment`

I would like to be able to detect such lines using kotlin's File forEachLine method. However I don't know how to do it.

The only thing I've been able to do is to find whenever a line contains a comment by doing :

```
File(fileName).forEachLine {
    
   if(it.contains("//")){
      println("There is a comment!")
   }

}
```

**I'm not interested in detecting comments but only those lines where there is code and a comment on the same line.**

Note: fileName is a java file ex: Test.java that we read line by line.

Comment: Does that work or not? Theoretically, it should.

Comment: I want to differentiate between the `//comment` and `int x = 10 //comment`. Those are two different cases. I want the latter.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be 100% reliable. I think that doing `String a = "//";` is rare. After thinking about it, It wouldn't be a huge deal to let it pass as  a comment.

Comment: then something like `it.contains("//") && ! it.trim().startswith("//")` ? (in Javaish syntax) or shorter : `if it.trim().indexOf("//") > 0` it is one of the lines you search for.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: `if (it.trim().lastIndexOf("//") > 0) { ... }` or as in `if (it.trim().lastIndexOf("//") > 0) { String comment = it.substring(it.lastIndexOf("//")).trim(); System.out.println(comment); }`.

Comment: A string constant containing `//` may be rare, but the answers here provide some examples!  (And thinking “Oh, this'll never happen to me…” is the sort of thing that leads to obscure bugs, complaints, and/or being woken up in the middle of the night…)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `split` and `filter` functions on each line of your file:

```kotlin
fun getCodeLinesWithComments(lines: ArrayList<String>): ArrayList<String> {
        val codeLinesWithComments = arrayListOf<String>()
        for (line in lines) {
            if (line.split("//").filter { it.isNotEmpty() }.count() == 2) {
                codeLinesWithComments.add(line)
            }
        }
        return codeLinesWithComments
    }
```